# Cannot display entire image within div

Tags: html, css

I am adding images to a carousel but the page only shows the top half of the image.  It seems the image is not fitting itself to the div, but rather the image renders to the page and I can only see the portion of it that is behind the div that I put it in.

How can I make it so that the entire image is fitted to be the same size as the div that it's in?

I have tried using object-fit, in CSS, but that has not helped me.

```
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="./photos/za.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="./photos/india.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="./photos/thai.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

What CSS can I use to ensure that the entire image is displayed within the div?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  As it stands, there are multiple things that could be affecting your images and we need to see more code to understand better what's happening

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="./photos/za.jpg" alt="Los Angeles"> </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="./photos/india.jpg" alt="Chicago">
        <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="./photos/thai.jpg" alt="New york"> </div>
</div>
```

removed the explicitly mentioned width

Comment: Remove the explicitly mentioned width

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to center an image in a parent div but it looks like you're trying to make a card with an image in the background. Under this assumption I'd look to using some absolute positioning and and transform to center the image. **This approach will remove the image from getting in the way of any other content in its parent div.**

The code will look something like this:

```css
.item {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item__img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Los Angeles">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Chicago">
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="New york">
  </div>
</div>
```

Breaking that down:

We define a height and width on the parent div `.item` and a `position: relative;`. The height and width + the positioning are what we're going to use to align our image with.

The image itself, `.item__img` is set to have a width of `100%`, which will stretch it to match the width of its parent, `.item` (which is `400px`). Then by positioning the image absolutely, we can move it relative to its parent. We set the top and left values to `50%`. This will move the image `50%` of the parent height and width away from the top left corner. Now with the transform we are translating the image back `-50%` of the image width. This will result in the image aligning centered in the parent div.

It's important to note that in this execution it is possible for the background image to be be too short to fit in the parent. It will always be centered but if the image isn't as tall as the parent it will not stretch to fill it.

---

If you're not looking to prevent the image from getting in the way of other content in the parent div, you can do something much simpler using `object-fit`. There are [a bunch of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) but the one that will likely be most helpful is `cover`. This will stretch the image to fit both height and width allowing it to crop whichever direction needs to. The code should look something like this:

```css
.item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.item__img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" alt="New york">
    </div>
  </div>
```